# Javascript event queue task sequence number?

Tags: javascript

Javascript's processing model, as described [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), is based on processing tasks from an event queue.

Is there, in any implementation (node, browser), a sequence number available that is incremented with each event.

Comment: Hard to see what a global sequence counter for all events could be used for. Have you seen `Date.now()`?

Comment: @Thankyou - Well, a millisecond is a long time to a computer. ;-)

Comment: We might be able to help better if we know what your use case was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to prove a negative but:

- There's certainly nothing in JavaScript itself
- There's nothing about one in the [HTML spec section](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loops) describing this for browsers
- There's nothing about one in the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) of its own event loop implementation

So I'm going with: No. :-)

*Timers* have unique handles (numbers on browsers, objects on Node.js), but other kinds of tasks have nothing exposes as far as I've ever seen.

Comment: Indeed, to prove the negative is difficult. I found nothing in the docs either, but that does not mean a thing given the amount of stuff available. So I accept this as a best effort confirmation until someone proves it wrong. :-)